# Raspberry Pi - run function for 5 seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi to blink a LED for 5 seconds, and then another one for 5 seconds as well. So I have two functions, one for blinking my red LED, and another for the blue one. I used `utime.sleep(0.5)` for the functions to turn off the LEDs every half second.

```
def blink_red():
  RED.toggle()
  BLUE.value(0)
  utime.sleep(0.5)

def blink_blue():
  BLUE.toggle()
  RED.value(0)
  utime.sleep(0.5)
```

For the execution of the code, I made use of `utime.sleep(5)` in hopes of getting each function to run for 5 seconds, however it doesn't make the LEDs blink. It turns the red led on for five seconds, and the blue one on for 5 seconds as well.

```
while True:
  blink_red()
  time.sleep(5)
  blink_blue()
  utime.sleep(5)
```

Which parts of my code do I need to change or is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Edit: I am running micropython

Comment: `utime` isn't a standard Python module. Are you running micropython or CircuitPython? Do the `RED.toggle()` and `BLUE.toggle()` functions, by themselves, do what you want (e.g., when running them from the interactive Python prompt)?

Comment: What *does* it make them do? Anything?

Comment: @larsks I am running micropython. the `toggle()` functions turn the LEDs on initially, but only toggles to off when `utime.sleep()` is called

Comment: @Laif added an edit. It turns the red led on for five seconds (while the blue one is off), and then turns the blue one on for 5 seconds (while red is off as well).

Answer (score 2):

> It turns the red led on for five seconds (while the blue one is off), and then turns the blue one on for 5 seconds (while red is off as well).

It sounds like your code is doing what you've asked it do do.

1. Your loop is running:

   ```
     blink_red()
     time.sleep(5)
     blink_blue()
     utime.sleep(5)
   ```
2. When you call `blink_red()`:

   ```
     # you toggle the RED LED (once)
     RED.toggle()

     # you turn off the blue LED
     BLUE.value(0)

     # you wait 0.5 seconds
     utime.sleep(0.5)

     # ...and then you return to the main loop
   ```
3. Now you're back in the loop, and you call `time.sleep(5)`.

Do you see where this is going?

If you wanted `blink_red()` to blink the red LED for five seconds, you would need something like:

```
def blink_red():
    BLUE.off()
    for i in range(5):
        RED.toggle()
        utime.sleep(0.5)
        RED.toggle()
        utime.sleep(0.5)
```

And your `while` loop would look like this:

```
while True:
  blink_red()
  blink_blue()
```

(Assuming that you rewrote `blink_blue` as well.)

---

Here's a complete program; I was running this using micropython on an ESP C3 (so it's possible it will have slightly different syntax than micropython on the Pi, but it should be largely the same):

```
try:
    import time
except ImportError:
    import utime as time

from machine import Pin


RED = Pin(3, Pin.OUT)
BLUE = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)

PINS = [RED, BLUE]


def blink_pin(pin):
    for i in range(5):
        pin.on()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pin.off()
        time.sleep(0.5)


# ensure everything is off to start
for pin in PINS:
    pin.off()

while True:
    blink_pin(RED)
    blink_pin(BLUE)
```